# How to change size of CodenameOne's OnOffSwitch component?

Tags: codenameone

I'm creating mobile app with CodenameOne and I want to show 3 OnOffSwitch components in one row, but they are too big on Android 4.0.3 and "on/off"-text is invisible.

How can I change size of OnOffSwitch component and make "on/off"-text visible? I tried `setSize(new Dimension(width, height))` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`setSize` is meant for usage in a layout manager not manually, you shouldn't use `setX`, `setY`,`setWidth`,`setHeight` etc.

You need to use a layout manager:

http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---positioning-components-using-layout-managers.html

E.g. the entire form can have a `BoxLayout` on the Y axis and the switches can be in a `Container` with a 3 column grid.

Comment: I have tried to do so, that's what I'm saying. When I put the switches in three columns, then on my device with Android 4.0.3 they are compressed in width, and text values(on/off) are not visible. I think it is due to the fact that the OnOffSwitch-component is too large in Android 4.0.3. Unfortunately I can not post the screenshot, so it would be more clear.

Comment: Buttons on Android are too wide so there might not be enough space for 3 in a phone. If you try it in a tablet you will see them fitting just fine. You can style the Button UIID and reduce its padding but you might need to redo the border to make it small enough which is probably something you wouldn't want to do.